# overload assignment operator (+=) and concatenate two string objects of class using new keyword

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I need to overload an assignment operator `+=` and concatenate two **MyString**(class) objects in C++.I'm using CodeBlocks.I need to allocte memory dynamically so I've to use **new** keyword to overload `+=` operator.The following is the code is used.

**MyString.h**

```
#ifndef MYSTRING_H
#define MYSTRING_H


class MyString
{
   private:
    const char* str;
    int length;
public:
    MyString();
    ~MyString();
    MyString(const char*);
    MyString(const MyString&);
    void operator = (const MyString&);
    int getLength() const;
    MyString operator + (const MyString&);
    MyString operator += (const MyString&);
    void display();
};

#endif // MYSTRING_H
```

**MyString.cpp**

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

MyString::MyString()
{
    str="\0";
    length=0;

}
MyString::MyString(const char* Str)
{
    str=Str;
    int str_length=0;

    while (str[str_length] != '\0') {
        str_length++;
    }
    length=str_length;
}
MyString::MyString(const MyString &temp)
{
    str=temp.str;
    length=temp.length;
}
void MyString::operator = (const MyString &deepcopy)
{
    str=deepcopy.str;
    length=deepcopy.length;
}

MyString MyString::operator += (const MyString& strrr)  // here I need to overload assignment operator with new keyword dynamically.
{

    str = str+strrr.str;    // this is not a correct code.
}

int MyString::getLength() const
{
    return length;
}

void MyString::display()
{
    std::cout << str<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "string length: " <<length<<std::endl;
}
MyString::~MyString()
{

}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <MyString.h>


int main()
{
    char str[20];
    MyString S1;
    std::cout << "Enter a string : " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> str;
    MyString S2(str);
    S2.display();
    MyString S3=S2;
    S3.display();
    MyString S4=S3;
    S4.display();
    MyString S5; // This S5 object that I'm trying to use to overload += operator
    S5 = S3 + S4;
    S5.display();
    return 0;
}
```

enter code here

Comment: What is your question? The only hint is a comment inline: `// this is not a correct code.` Why not? What happens when you compile/run it? What should happen instead? Then there is `// here I need to overload assignment operator with new keyword dynamically.` What does this mean? Why do you need to do that? Please clarify your precise question.

Comment: Have you tested your constructor, and copy constructor, to see if they work? Do that before writing `operator+=`.

Comment: The code is okay,runs fine except I don't know how to overload (+=) operator and concatenate two objects of class.The code that I need you to look at is:        
                                                                                                                         MyString MyString::operator += (const MyString& strrr)  // here I need to overload assignment operator with new keyword dynamically.
{

    str = str+strrr.str;    // this is not a correct code.
}

Comment: and in main.cpp file object S5 to concatenate S3 and S4.

Comment: You are missing dynamic allocation in 5 or 6 places, not just one.